# Android project deployment on device: app is misconfigured

Tags: android

I created an Android project which includes many activities (maps and list views and Facebook login). It's running perfectly on the emulator, but when I deploy it on a device it's giving me an error on connecting to the Facebook app.

The error is:

> (app is mis-configured for Facebook login with a hash key value is also shown)

The hash value that is prompted is not the same that I put in the Facebook hash key. There is just a difference of a "=" sign at the end.

I found many questions relative to this issue, but none of them solved my problem.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two possibilities

whether your hash key value is wrong or the sand box value in graph explorer facebook is turned off(disabled).turn this on with right right app hash key.